# having an issue related to dev/sda5 mounting. when booting up the screen goes as recovering journal and dev/sda5 clear blocks.target is busy issue

Tags: boot, partitioning, recovery-mode

```
/dev/loop9 853M 853M 0 100% /snap/intellij-idea-community/483
/dev/loop13 667M 667M 0 100% /snap/onlyoffice-desktopeditors/181
$ sudo parted /dev/sda 'print'
[sudo] password for prithivira
Model: ATA ST500LT012-1DG14 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logicat/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number Start End Size Type File system Flags
1 1049kB 538MB 537MB primary fat32 boot
2 539MB 50GB 500GB extended
5 539MB 500GB 500GB logical ext4

$ sudo umount /dev/sdb
umount: /dev/sdb: no mount point specified.
$ sudo umount /dev/sdas
umount: /: target is busy.
$ sudo fsck /dev/sda5
fsck from util-Linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/sda5 is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

$ sudo fsck -N /dev/sdas
fsck from util-linux 2.34
[/usr/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /] fsck.ext4 /dev/sda5
$ sudo fsck -y /dev/sdas
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
/dev/sdaS is mounted.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/536955/e2fsck-cannot-continue-aborting)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I safely fsck my root partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1090066/how-can-i-safely-fsck-my-root-partition)

Comment: 1. You can't umount your root partition 2. You can't fsck a mounted partition without causing further data loss 3. You need to use a LiveCD like the linked question 4. You use the mount path not the device path for umount (unlike the fsck syntax)