How to fix "You are in emergency mode"
I cannot boot into Ubuntu, a black screen appears with the inscription
You are in emergency mode. After logging in, type `journalctl -xb` to view system logs, `systemctl reboot`, `systemctl default`, or `exit`
to boot into default mode.
Press enter for maintenance
or press Control-D to continue. 

After I have entered exit, this message appears:
"failed to start default target transaction for graphical.target/start is destructive"

Here are the conclusions from the commands.

Previously, I tried to allocate more space for the /dev/sda6 device using the parted command as a superuser. I used the commands parted and (parted) p, along the way I forgot to inform the Linux kernel about this.

How to fix it?

What is the issue? There are no details here as to what you did or why to get this. Please edit the question and fill in some details. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Fixed it, can you help?

Where is the version of Ubuntu? Anyway if you messed with the partitions you have corrupted the info on the hard drive most likely beyond repair. Time to reinstall the 2 OS .

Version of my Ubuntu is 24.04 LTS. I think that. I think I'm having problems with /dev/sda6 since it's mounted. E.g. when I enter fsck /dev/sda6 a message appears containing "/dev/sda6 is mounted e2fsck: cannot continue: aborting". Do you know what this is related to?

Some insight for the e2fsck error: https://askubuntu.com/q/536955/ (put every distinct error message straight into a web search)

This question is similar to: What does this message mean and what to do to let my Ubuntu boot? "... You are in emergency mode. ...". If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
